# Append data from file to list

Tags: python, string, append

I am trying to append data read in from a file. Suppose the file has the following text:

```
cat
dog
bird
```

I've created a list, called 'net' which I want to add each string together such that the outcome is:

```
cat dog bird
```

Below is an example of what I currently have:

```
net = []
with open(out_file, 'r+') as fin:
 data = fin.read().splitlines(True)

net.append(data[0]+data[1]+data[2])
```

This works but the file I am using has certain conditions that could make this operation up to:

```
net.append(data[0]+data[1]+data[2]+...+data[20])
```

Is there a way I could simplify this operation? Such that it knows whether to do:

```
net.append(data[0]+data[1]+data[2]+data[3]+data[4])
```

or:

```
net.append(data[0]+data[1]+data[2]+data[3]+data[4]+data[5]+data[6]+data[7]+data[8])
```

EDIT: I should clarify. I don't want to combine every single string from the file. For example, I might want to combine only 'cat' and 'dog' and ignore 'bird.'

Comment: If you want to join the strings again why do you split them first?

Comment: `net.extend(data)`

Answer (score 1):

```
net = []
with open(out_file, 'r+') as fin:
    net.append(''.join(fin.readlines()))
```

Comment: What if I only want to join 'cat' and 'dog' and ignore 'bird'?

Comment: net.append(''.join([i for i fin.readlines() if i != 'bird']))

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `for loop`.

```
for elem in data:
    net.append(elem)
```

If you would like the whole list as a string, just use `join`.

```
net.append(' '.join(data))
```

Comment: How could I specify which elements to use? For example, say I am in the middle of my file at line 100 and want to combine lines 100 + 101 + 102 together?

Comment: instead of data, use data[100:102]